How does extensive conjunction cause molecules to appear black?
When an organic molecule is only mildly conjugated, it would be able to absorb wavelengths in the ultraviolet region, when more conjugation is present, a molecule with then be able to absorb wavelengths in the visible region, beginning with the ability to absorb the highest energy visible light, violet, this would make the molecule appear yellow, its complementary color. If it is even more conjugated, it would absorb blue and we would see orange. After more conjugation it would absorb green and it would appear red and as this goes on it would be able to absorb the lowest frequency visible light, red, and would appear green.
First of all is this accurate and true? Because this is what I understood from my spectroscopy course.
If this is true, when do they appear black? What happens to their structure that makes them absorb all visible light?

In theory yes, extended conjugation will lower the $\pi \rightarrow \pi^{}$ transition (or NB $\rightarrow \pi^{}$ transitions) enough to make the molecule appear black. That said, I don't really know many "normal" black organic molecules. Carbon black comes to mind, but that structure is quite the marvel.

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23608/is-it-possible-to-make-broad-spectrum-light-absorbing-paint https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51643/which-single-organic-molecule-has-strong-absorbance-throughout-the-visible-range https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/185189/maximum-of-light-absorption-v-s-color-of-complex https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110966/highly-conjugated-compounds-and-the-effects-of-substiuents

Even thin films of polyacetylene appear almost completely black due to extensive conjugation due to many closely lying energy levels. Think of a particle in a box as the box gets bigger, the energy levels get closer together and so can absorb a wider range of photon energies.

When a conjugate molecule is long enough, the available energy levels are separated by smaller and smaller intervals. At the limit, these levels are nearly continuous, and all wavelengths can be absorbed. When all wavelengths can be absorbed, this is the definition of a black body.
